# Filter Google Book API for Children's Books

Tags: api, google-api, google-books

I'm using the google book api (e.g., https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=trees) and I want to filter the results to only display children's books.  [I see there is](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#PerformingSearch) a "subject:" addition to the query but I can't tell if that truly works. Do I just use 'q=[mysearchterm] subject:children'?